# Agregar un select a partir de otro Javascript

Tags: javascript, select

necesito ayuda con las listas desplegables/select, me he perdido un poco. Quiero que se me muestre un select "provincias" según la comunidad autónoma que hayamos seleccionado antes. Los datos están guardados en un array.

Creo una variable vector que accedera al indice de provincias `var vector=provincias[indice]`. Nueva variable para dar nombre al segundo select.

CReamos el bucle for que va a recorrer todos los indices del vector. Vamos a añadir una nueva opción con `new Option(vector[i],i)`

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

 
 var provincias=[[['Jaen'],['Cordoba'],['Sevilla'], ['Huelva'],['Cadiz'], ['Malaga'], ['Granada'], ['Almeria']];

 


 function mostrarProvincias(incdice){
  
  var vector=provincias[indice];
  var lst1=document.getElementById('provincias');
  var nuevaOpcion;

  for (var i=0;i<vector.length;i++) {

   nuevaOpcion = new Option(vector[i],i);
   lst1.options[lst1.length]=nuevaOpcion;
  }
  

 }

</script>
```

```html
<body>
  <tr>
   <select onclick="mostrarProvincias()" id="lista1">
    <option value="and">Andalucía</option>
    <option value="ara">Aragón</option>
    <option value="lrio">La Rioja</option>
    <option value="bal">Islas Baleares</option>
    <option value="cat">Cataluña</option>
    <option value="cana" >Canarias</option>
    <option value="cant">Cantabria</option>
    <option value="casM">Castilla-La Mancha</option>
    <option value="casL">Castilla y León</option>
    <option value="mad">Comunidad de Madrid</option>
    <option value="nav">Comunidad Foral de Navarra</option>
    <option value="val" >Comunidad Valenciana</option>
    <option value="ext">Extremadura</option>
    <option value="gal">Galicia</option>
    <option value="pvas">País Vasco</option>
    <option value="ast">Principado de Asturias</option>
    <option value="mur">Región de Murcia</option>

  </select> 

  <select id="provincias">
    <option value="Comunidad Valenciana" selected>Comunidad Valenciana</option>
    <option value="can">Islas Canarias</option>
    <option value="mad">Madrid</option>
    <option value="and">Andalucía</option>
    <option value="gal">Galicia</option>
    <option value="ext">Extremadura</option>
  </select>

 <tr>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buscando un poco por internet lo sacas fácil

```js
for (var i=0;i<vector.length;i++) {
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = vector[i];
lst1.add(option);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En vez de `onclick` usaré `onchange`, esto se activa cada vez que se cambia el valor del `select`. Al cambiar el valor se llama a la función, en mi caso la nombraré `elegir()`.

En este ejemplo usaré otros valores para las opciones del `select`:

1. Primer `select`: Valores *Uno* y *Diez*.
2. Segundo `select`. Si en el primer `select` se elige:
   2.1. *Uno*: Valores: *Dos* y *Tres*.
   2.2. *Diez*: Valores: *Veinte* y *Treinta*.

```
var valores = [
    ["Uno",["Dos","Tres"]]
    ,["Diez",["Veinte","Treinta"]]
];
```

#### Función `elegir()`:

1. Se declaran variables para cada `select`:

   ```
   var primer_seleccionador = document.getElementById("x1")
   var segundo_seleccionador = document.getElementById("x10")
   ```
2. A partir del array de `valores`, mediante `map` se recupera una lista de las opciones del primer `select`:

   ```
   var lista = valores.map(function(x){return x[0]})
   ```

   Esto significa que se obtiene un array como el siguiente:

   > `[ "Uno", "Diez" ]` Lo llamaremos `lista`.
3. Se obtiene la opción seleccionada del primer `select`, puede ser *Uno* o *Diez*, en este caso usaré *Diez*:

   ```
   var seleccionado = primer_seleccionador.value
   ```
4. Se obtiene la posición donde se encuentra la opción seleccionada del primer `select`, que en este caso es `lista`, comenzando las posiciones en *0*. Como dijimos en el **paso 3**, buscaremos *Diez* en la lista del **paso 2**, que es `[ "Uno", "Diez" ]`

   ```
   var posición = lista.indexOf(seleccionado)
   ```

   El resultado para la `posición` es *1*, como se muestra en la siguiente tabla:

   ```
    [ "Uno", "Diez" ]
         0       1 <= Se encuentra "Diez" aquí.
   ```
5. A partir de la `posición` encontrada y la lista de `valores`, creamos la lista de opciones para el segundo `select`.

   ```
   var nueva_lista = valores[posición]
   ```

   Primero elegimos *la sub-lista* de `valores` que esté en la `posición`, que es *1*:

   ```
   var valores=[
       ["Uno",["Dos","Tres"]] // Si posición fuera 0
       ,["Diez",["Veinte","Treinta"]] //  Si fuera 1. Sí, es 1, elegimos esta
   ];
   ```

   Entonces obtenemos que `nueva_lista` es:

   > `["Diez",["Veinte","Treinta"]]`

   No nos interesa el primer valor, ya que pertenece al primer `select`. Entonces por eso usamos `[1]` en `valores[posición][1]`, para obtener solo las opciones del segundo `select`. Entonces obtendremos lo siguiente:

   > `["Veinte","Treinta"]`
6. Vaciamos el segundo `select`:

   ```
   segundo_seleccionador.innerHTML = ""
   ```
7. A partir de la nueva lista creada (`nueva_lista`) en el **paso 5**, se lo recorre con `map` y se van creando opciones mediante `new Option`, aunque bien podría ser con `document.createElement("option")` y se las va agregando al segundo `select`.

   ```
   nueva_lista.map(function(x){
       var nueva_opción = new Option(x)
       segundo_seleccionador.appendChild(nueva_opción)
   })
   ```

   Entonces, al elegir en el primer `select` el *Diez*, en el segundo `select` estarán las opciones *Veinte* y *Treinta*.

Código completo:

```js
var valores=[
 ["Uno",["Dos","Tres"]]
 ,["Diez",["Veinte","Treinta"]]
]
function elegir(){
 var primer_seleccionador = document.getElementById("x1")
 var segundo_seleccionador = document.getElementById("x10")
 var lista = valores.map(function(x){return x[0]})
 var seleccionado = primer_seleccionador.value
 var posición = lista.indexOf(seleccionado)
 var nueva_lista = valores[posición][1]
 segundo_seleccionador.innerHTML = ""
 nueva_lista.map(function(x){
  var nueva_opción = new Option(x)
  segundo_seleccionador.appendChild(nueva_opción)
 })
 console.log( JSON.stringify(nueva_lista) )
}
```

```html
<select onchange="elegir()" id="x1">
 <option>Uno</option>
 <option>Diez</option>
</select>
<select id="x10">
 <option selected>Diez</option>
 <option>Veinte</option>
</select>
```